# Routing between a controller and razor page in ASP.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to route from an action method in the home controller to a razor page. What's the correct way?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoom(string name)
{
  db.Chats.Add(new Chat
    {
      Name = name,
      Type = ChatType.Room
    });
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Redirect("../Pages/Index");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "RedirectToPage" method to redirect to a Razor page in asp.net core.

RedirectToPage method returns a new instance of RedirectToPageResult (a form of ActionResult). RedirectToPage method is a helper method that comes with PageModel and helps to eliminate the need to write up a new instance of an action result and simplify the code.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoom(string name)
    {
        _db.Chats.Add(new Chat
        {
            Name = name,
            Type = ChatType.Room
        });
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("Index");//assuming you have the Index page in Pages folder
    }
```

fyi, RedirectToPage also has overloads and you can use it based on your need.

The above code has same effect as below.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoom(string name)
    {
        _db.Chats.Add(new Chat
        {
            Name = name,
            Type = ChatType.Room
        });
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
    }
```